# change css styles of active admin

Tags: activeadmin

I'm looking to adjust the style of active admin's UI. Although I haven't been able to find any style sheets in the project. Does anyone know where the style sheets are located so that they can be modified?

Comment: realized that I had to generate the active admin styles in my rails app. before  it was referencing the stylesheet within the gem, which was not included in the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add your css to `active_admin.css.scss` located in the `app/assets/stylesheets` folder.

that file is for that, to override active_admin styles